# NodeJS Equaltiy Check Failing

Tags: node.js

I do not understand why this equality check is failing in my NodeJS file:

```js
const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
const extension = pathParsed.ext;
let pathname = parsedUrl.pathname;
if (extension === '.api') {
    // API requests, manually map and change extension
    contentType = mimeTypeMap['.json'];
    pathname = path.join(`${pathDirectory}/${pathFilename}.js`);
}
// this list will eventually grow
const apiModules = [
    {
        endpoint: '\\api\\user\\get.js',
        module: require('./api/user/get.js')
    }
];
const module = apiModules.find(m => {
    console.log('Pathname: ' + pathname);
    console.log('Endpoint: ' + m.endpoint);
    return m.endpoint === pathname;
});
```

This is what gets printed to the console:

```
Pathname: \api\user\get.js
Endpoint: \api\user\get.js
```

However, my `module` variable is undefined, telling me that the equality check is failing.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're using module twice. Second, module shouldn't be used as a variable in node as it's already a [nodejs global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).

Most importantly, your issue isn't in your example code. It may be related to the input to parsedUrl. Here's a pared down, working example:

```
./example.js
const parsedUrl = { pathname: '\\api\\user\\get.js' };
let pathname = parsedUrl.pathname;
// this list will eventually grow
const apiModules = [
    {
        endpoint: '\\api\\user\\get.js',
        module: require('./api/user/get.js')
    }
];
const result = apiModules.find(m => {
    console.log('Pathname: ' + pathname);
    console.log('Endpoint: ' + m.endpoint);
    return m.endpoint === pathname;
});

console.log(result);
```

With supporting module:

```
./api/user/get.js
module.exports = { payload: "Success" };
```

Output:

```
Pathname: \api\user\get.js
Endpoint: \api\user\get.js
{ endpoint: '\\api\\user\\get.js',
  module: { payload: 'Success' } }
```